# Shell Removing Tabs/Spaces

Tags: grep

I've used a grep command with sed and cut filters that basically turns my output to something similar to this

```
    this line 1


    this line 2


    another line 3


    another line 4
```

I'm trying to get an output without the spaces in between the lines and in front of the lines so it'd look like

```
this line 1
this line 2
another line 3
another line 4
```

I'd like to add another | filter

Answer (score 12):

Add this filter to remove whitespace from the beginning of the line and remove blank lines, notice that it uses two `sed` commands, one to remove leading whitespace and another to delete lines with no content

```
| sed -e 's/^\s*//' -e '/^$/d'
```

There is an example in [the Wikipedia article for sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) which  uses the d command to delete lines that are either blank or only contain spaces, my solution uses the escape sequence `\s` to match any whitespace character (space, tab, and so on), here is the Wikipedia example:

```
sed -e '/^ *$/d' inputFileName
```

- The caret (^) matches the beginning of the line.
- The dollar sign ($) matches the end of the line.
- The asterisk (*) matches zero or more occurrences of the previous character.

Comment: This was the first answer to work for me after trying the answers higher above in this list.

Answer (score 11):

This can be done with the `tr` command as well. Like so

`| tr -s [:space:]`

or alternatively

`| tr -s \\n`

if you want to remove the line breaks only, without the space chars in the beginning of each line.

Comment: Won't the first command `tr -s [:space:]` leave one leading blank? - It squeezes all but one of consecutive whitespace characters.

Comment: +1 for an easy method. any idea how could I keep the colors from egrep?

Comment: I found `| tr -d [:blank:]` to work well and it got rid of the extra space at the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

I would do this, short and simple:

```
sed 's: ::g'
```

Add this at the end of your command, and all whitespace will go poof. For example try this command:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | sed 's: ::g'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use grep:

```
... | grep -o '[^$(printf '\t') ].*'
```

Here we print lines that have at least one character that isn't white space. By using the "-o" flag, we print only the match, and we force the match to start on a non white space character.

EDIT: Changed command so it can remove the leading white space characters.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Nice... but it won't remove leading whitespace in non-blank lines.

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed that =/ Hopefully this solution fixes it

Comment: In my system this removes the character 't' instead of the tab character

Comment: `echo ' try this' | grep -o '[^\t ].*'` results in `ry this`

Comment: Thanks again! I forgot that grep doesn't support escaped tab characters. Used printf as a more portable work around.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep "^." filename` to remove blank lines while printing.Here,the lines starting with any character is matched so that the blank lines are left out.
`^` indicates start of the line.
`.` checks for any character.

Answer (score 0):

```
(whateverproducesthisoutput)|sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+//'|grep -v '^$'
```

(depending on your `sed`, you can replace `[[:space:]]` with `\s`).

Answer (score 0):

**Remove spaces and tabs:**

```
echo $'spaces    tabs\ttabs' | tr -d '\t '
```

Output: `spacestabstabs`

**Remove tabs only:**

```
echo $'spaces    tabs\ttabs' | tr -d '\t'
```

Output: `spaces    tabstabs`

**Remove spaces only:**

```
echo $'spaces    tabs\ttabs' | tr -d ' '
```

Output: `spacestabs tabs`

Comment: -d, --delete            delete characters in ARRAY1... ARRAYs are specified as strings of characters.  Most represent themselves.